# UITableView with custom cell class showing correct number of rows but all blank

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I can't seem to figure out why the cells are all blank in my table with custom cells. I've been searching and trying suggestions for a while now but can't figure it out. At this point I feel like I'm missing something obvious

This is my .swift

```
import UIKit

struct Contact {

    var name:String
    var title:String
    var phone:String

}

class ContactTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var contactName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactPhone: UILabel!

}

class Contacts:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var contactTable: UITableView!

    var contactData = [
        Contact(name: "Main Office", title: "Title", phone: "Phone Here"),
        Contact(name: "Joe Bloggs", title: "Title Here", phone: "Phone Number"),
        Contact(name: "John Smith", title: "Another Title", phone: "Another Phone")
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        contactTable.register(ContactTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        contactTable.delegate = self
        contactTable.dataSource = self

    }

    func tableView(_ contactTable: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.contactData.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(contactTable: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ contactTable: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let contactCell = contactTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ContactTableViewCell

        let contact = contactData[indexPath.row]

        contactCell.contactName?.text = contact.name
        contactCell.contactTitle?.text = contact.title
        contactCell.contactPhone?.text = contact.phone

        return contactCell

    }

}
```

My IBOutlets are definitely linked, and the cell is linked to the ContactTableViewClass

[image]

This is how my cell looks

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment this line

```
contactTable.register(ContactTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
```

And set the identifier `cellId` to the cell in IB , When you create a prototype cell , don't register it , as the register occurs automatically

In your case all outlets are nil

```
// try contactCell.contactName.text and it' ll crash
contactCell.contactName?.text = contact.name
contactCell.contactTitle?.text = contact.title
contactCell.contactPhone?.text = contact.phone
```

As you override IB registration with a class whose layout is created in IB as `ContactTableViewCell.self` is when you completely create the class with it's layout programmatically

Comment: Well, damn, it was something that simple after all. Thank you. I can't believe all that searching didn't result in that